# count elements in a html var in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

i m doing a ajax call with which i m getting data (html) which is having the structure

```
 <li>
<div class="min-height">
    <a href="auser.jsp?id=7"><img src="dir/image_759.jpeg"alt="image" /></a><br />
    sumit jha
</div>
</li>
```

Now before adding it the dom i want to count the number of li 's  in the html

as for example

```
$.ajax( {
type: "POST",
url: "more_people.jsp",
data: ({last_id: last_id  }),
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
    $li = html;
    console.log ( $li.html().children().length );
}
});
```

How do i do??

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [`.filter()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the result:

```
success: function(html) {
    console.log($(html).filter("li").length);
}
```

Comment: answer right.. find is for ol > li level... not at the same level or at ol level..

Comment: @Pradyut: I don't understand. With the given HTML structure from your question, the `<li>` nodes are top leveled. In this case you need to invoke `.filter()` or to wrap the result around an extra-node to use `.find()`.

Comment: some misunderstanding... your answer is right...no issues.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
html = '<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>';
var temp = document.createElement('<div>');
temp.innerHTML = html;
alert(temp.getElementsByTagName('li').length);
```

Comment: jAndy answer is right... u r frm rus?? i like rus... and raw javascript...:D btw do ur answer without any temp using only the html...

Comment: :-) I'm English, surname is Polish, first name is better indication of nationality usually.  Without the temp var?  I don't think you can set the innerHTML then invoke getElementsByTagName without some sort of reference.  Well, in IE you can do document.createElement(html).getElementsByTagName('li').length but I'm not sure that's cross-browser.